# Unit-testing authorization policies in Rails with RSpec

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, ruby-on-rails, rspec, authorization

The following specs test the authorization setup of the `Post` resource in a Rails 4.2 application. The Pundit gem is used for authorization but I believe the specs be easily adapted to work with most role-based authorization setups. The code was inspired by [this blog post](http://www.thunderboltlabs.com/blog/2013/03/27/testing-pundit-policies-with-rspec/).

The `User` model `has_many :posts` and the `Post` model `belongs_to :user`.

The code works as expected but it would be great to receive feedback and suggestions from more experienced developers.

#### Custom Matcher

```
RSpec::Matchers.define :permit do |action|
  match do |policy|
    policy.public_send("#{action}?")
  end

  failure_message do |policy|
    "#{policy.class} does not permit #{action} on #{policy.record} for #{policy.user.inspect}."
  end

  failure_message_when_negated do |policy|
    "#{policy.class} does not forbid #{action} on #{policy.record} for #{policy.user.inspect}."
  end
end
```

#### Specs

```
require 'rails_helper'
require 'support/pundit_matcher'

describe PostPolicy do
  describe 'scope' do
    # The following "let" and "subject" blocks use variables defined within
    # other "let" blocks (user and scope). That's possible due to lazy loading.
    subject(:policy_scope) { PostPolicy::Scope.new(user,Post.all).resolve }
    let(:associated_post) { FactoryGirl.create(:post, user: user) }
    let!(:unassociated_post) { FactoryGirl.create(:post, user: nil) }

    context "for an unauthenticated user" do
      let(:user) { nil }
      it "hides all posts" do
        # unassociated_post is eagerly created so it exists within this test.
        expect(policy_scope).to eq nil
      end
    end

    context "for an ordinary user" do
      let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
      it "only shows posts associated with the user" do
        expect(policy_scope).to eq [associated_post]
      end
    end

    context "for an admin user" do
      let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:admin_user) }
      it "shows unpublished post" do
        expect(policy_scope).to include(associated_post, unassociated_post)
      end
    end
  end

  describe 'policy' do
    subject { PostPolicy.new(user, post) }
    let(:post) { FactoryGirl.create(:post, user: nil) }

    context "for an unauthenticated user" do
      let(:user) { nil }

      it { is_expected.to permit(:show) }
      it { is_expected.not_to permit(:create) }
      it { is_expected.not_to permit(:new) }
      it { is_expected.not_to permit(:update) }
      it { is_expected.not_to permit(:edit) }
      it { is_expected.not_to permit(:destroy) }
    end

    context "for an ordinary user" do
      let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }

      it { is_expected.to permit(:create) }
      it { is_expected.to permit(:new) }

      context "and a post that is NOT associated to that user" do
        it { is_expected.to permit(:show) }
        it { is_expected.not_to permit(:update) }
        it { is_expected.not_to permit(:edit) }
        it { is_expected.not_to permit(:destroy) }
      end

      context "and a post that IS associated to that user" do
        let(:post) { FactoryGirl.create(:post, user: user) }

        it { is_expected.to permit(:show) }
        it { is_expected.to permit(:update) }
        it { is_expected.to permit(:edit) }
        it { is_expected.to permit(:destroy) }
      end
    end

    context "for an admin" do
      let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:admin_user) }

      it { is_expected.to permit(:show) }
      it { is_expected.to permit(:create) }
      it { is_expected.to permit(:new) }
      it { is_expected.to permit(:update) }
      it { is_expected.to permit(:edit) }
      it { is_expected.to permit(:destroy) }
    end
  end
end
```